# Ordering for month/week tabs

Tags: support, top-questions

What kind or ordering is used for questions in month/week tabs? Tooltip text says:

> [image: tooltip]

But I can't understand sort criteria. All of questions presented in the following picture were asked in December:

> [image: ordering]